# How to make for loop break when no value entered for first name

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement, break

I can not get my code to break at the first name, It will only break after i have left all values blank.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>


void main(void) { //Start main function

    // Declare variables
    char charTempArray[50] = "";
    char charFirstNames[50][50];
    char charLastNames[50][50];
    char charTempSal[10] = "";
    int intSalaries[50];
    int intSalarySum = 0;
    int intSalaryAvg = 0;
    int intSalaryTop = 0;
    int intSalaryBot = 9999999999;
    int intArraySize = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int intCharConv = 0;

    //User input to build the arrays
    for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
        if (charFirstNames[i - 1][0] != '\0') {
            printf("Please enter Employees first name.\n ");
            gets(charTempArray);
            strcpy(charFirstNames[i], charTempArray);
            printf("Please enter Employees last name.\n ");
            gets(charTempArray);
            strcpy(charLastNames[i], charTempArray);
            printf("Please enter Employees salary.\n ");
            gets(charTempSal);
            intCharConv = atoi(charTempSal);
            intSalaries[i] = intCharConv;
            intArraySize = i;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
```

Here is the output.

```
Please enter Employees first name.
 test
Please enter Employees last name.
 me
Please enter Employees salary.
 100
Please enter Employees first name.

Please enter Employees last name.

Please enter Employees salary.

Teacher 1: test me      Salary(per year):100

The average salary is:100 per year
The top salary is 100
The bottom salary is 100
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `if` will try to access an element outside the bounds of the array when `i=0`. Second you should test for empty first name right after you get the first name:

```
for(i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
{
    printf("Please enter Employees first name.\n ");
    gets(charTempArray);
    strcpy(charFirstNames[i], charTempArray);
    if(charTempArray[0] == 0)
        break;
    printf("Please enter Employees last name.\n ");
    gets(charTempArray);
    strcpy(charLastNames[i], charTempArray);
    printf("Please enter Employees salary.\n ");
    gets(charTempSal);
    intCharConv = atoi(charTempSal);
    intSalaries[i] = intCharConv;
    intArraySize = i;
}
```

Comment: I had tried this but I forgot to brace the for loop and had a break outside a loop so it did not work. Thank you.